# Intuitionistic Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, dependent-type, type-theory

I have been looking into intuitionistic logic and what is called "negative fragment" of intuitionistic propositional logic. However, I was not able to find any resource that explains the reason why it is called "negative fragment".

Any references/suggestions?

Comment: Could you please include a reference where you found that? This might help us give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: Was mentioned by Robert Harper (see http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/courses/hott/notes/notes_week1.pdf and http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/courses/hott/). He mentions it towards the end of lecture 1 and he explicitly does not get into the reason on why "negative fragment" is the name. This made me curious, but I could not find a good reason. Maybe later in the lectures he will explain, but it felt as this is something well "known".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Negative translations not intuitionistically
equivalent to the usual ones](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0317.pdf),

> The image of the usual negative translations is (essentially) the negative fragment
> NF, that is the set of all formulas without ∨ and ∃ and whose atomic formulas are
> all negated

If you look at the rules given at page 3 (or [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#TraClaIntLog)), it should be unsurprising that the translation is called negative. The fragment as defined by Harper removes the requirement that

> atomic formulas are
> all negated